# Integral of rational trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometric-integrals

I would need some help trying to evaluate the following integral:

$$
  I =  \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1-\cos \left(2n u\right)}{2 \cos \left(u\right)-x}\mathrm{d}u,
$$
where $|x|>2$ and $n=1,2,3,4,\dots$. However I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: My first thought would be to try a combination of a double-angle identity for cosine and a $u = \tan(x/2)$ and see what happens.

Comment: $$I(n,x)=\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi \frac{1-\cos(2n u)}{2 \cos u-x}du=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{1-\cos(2n u)}{2 \cos u-x}du=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1-\cos(2n u)}{2 \cos u-x}du$$
$$=\frac1{2\pi}\Re\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1-e^{2nui}}{e^{ui}+e^{-ui}-x}du=\frac1{2\pi}\Re\,-i\oint_{|z=1|} \frac{1-z^n}{z^2-zx+1}du$$
Only one root of the denominator is inside the circle $|z|=1$, therefore
$$I(n,x)=\underset{z=\frac x2-\sqrt{(\frac x2)^2-1}}{Res}\,\frac{1-z^n}{z^2-zx+1}=\frac{\big(\frac x2-\sqrt{(\frac x2)^2-1}\,\big)^n-1}{2\sqrt{(\frac x2)^2-1}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Define the function $\mathcal{I}{\left(n,a\right)}$ by the integral

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(n,a\right)}:=\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{1-\cos{\left(2n\varphi\right)}}{1-a\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}};~~~\small{n\in\mathbb{N}\land a\in(-1,1)}.$$

Note: the original integral from the OP in terms of the function above would then be

$$I=-\frac{1}{\pi\,x}\mathcal{I}{\left(n,\frac{2}{x}\right)};~~~\small{|x|>2}.$$

---

Consider the following Fourier cosine series:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p^{k}\cos{\left(k\varphi\right)}=\frac{1-p\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}{1-2p\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}+p^{2}};~~~\small{|p|<1\land\varphi\in\mathbb{R}},$$

$$\implies-1+2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p^{k}\cos{\left(k\varphi\right)}=\frac{1-p^{2}}{1-2p\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}+p^{2}}.$$

With the help of this Fourier expansion, we can then derive the following integration formula with relative ease: for any $m\in\mathbb{N}\land p\in(-1,1)$,

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{\left(1-p^{2}\right)\cos{\left(m\varphi\right)}}{1-2p\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}+p^{2}}
&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\cos{\left(m\varphi\right)}\left[-1+2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p^{k}\cos{\left(k\varphi\right)}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\left[-\cos{\left(m\varphi\right)}+2\cos{\left(m\varphi\right)}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p^{k}\cos{\left(k\varphi\right)}\right]\\
&=-\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\cos{\left(m\varphi\right)}+2\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\cos{\left(m\varphi\right)}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p^{k}\cos{\left(k\varphi\right)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p^{k}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\cos{\left(m\varphi\right)}\cos{\left(k\varphi\right)}\\
&=\pi\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p^{k}\delta_{m\,k}\\
&=\pi\,p^{m}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Now, suppose $n\in\mathbb{N}\land a\in(-1,1)$. Set $p:=\frac{a}{1+\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}$, and note that $-1<p<1$ and $a=\frac{2p}{1+p^{2}}$. We then obtain the following result for the integral $\mathcal{I}$:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(n,a\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{1-\cos{\left(2n\varphi\right)}}{1-a\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{1}{1-a\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}-\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{\cos{\left(2n\varphi\right)}}{1-a\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2}{1+t^{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-a\cos{\left(2\arctan{\left(t\right)}\right)}};~~~\small{\left[\varphi=2\arctan{\left(t\right)}\right]}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{\cos{\left(2n\varphi\right)}}{1-\frac{2p}{1+p^{2}}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2}{1+t^{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-a\left(\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}\right)}-\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{\left(1+p^{2}\right)\cos{\left(2n\varphi\right)}}{1+p^{2}-2p\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2}{\left(1+t^{2}\right)-a\left(1-t^{2}\right)}-\frac{1+p^{2}}{1-p^{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{\left(1-p^{2}\right)\cos{\left(2n\varphi\right)}}{1-2p\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}+p^{2}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2}{\left(1-a\right)+\left(1+a\right)t^{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{\left(1-p^{2}\right)\cos{\left(2n\varphi\right)}}{1-2p\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}+p^{2}}\\
&=\frac{2}{\left(1+a\right)\sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{1+t^{2}}-\frac{\pi\,p^{2n}}{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}-\frac{\pi\,p^{2n}}{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}\left[1-\left(\frac{a}{1+\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}\right)^{2n}\right].\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

---